# How to run selenium tests with maven?

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, maven, automated-tests, integration-testing

i want to run selenium test with maven as part of build, so here's my configuration:

```
    <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>2.1.1</version>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
    </plugin>



    <plugin>

        <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
        <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.4</version>
        <configuration>

            <wait>false</wait> 
            <container>
             <containerId>tomcat7x</containerId>
             <home>${env.CATALINA_HOME}</home>  
             <timeout>300000</timeout> <!-- 5 minutes -->                   
            </container>

            <configuration>
             <type>standalone</type>
             <home>target/tomcat7x</home>  
            </configuration>

            <properties>
              <cargo.jvmargs>-XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled</cargo.jvmargs>
            </properties>

        </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                <id>start-container</id>
                <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>start</goal>
                        <goal>deploy</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                <id>stop-container</id>
                <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>stop</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
    </plugin> 



    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <executions>
                <execution>
                <id>start</id>
                <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>start-server</goal>
                    </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <background>true</background>
                    <logOutput>true</logOutput>
                </configuration>
            </execution>

            <execution>
            <id>stop</id>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>stop-server</goal>
                    </goals>
            </execution> 
        </executions>
  </plugin>

    <plugin>

            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version>

            <configuration>
                <junitArtifactName>
                org.junit:com.springsource.org.junit
                </junitArtifactName>
                <excludes>

                    <exclude>**/unit/*Test.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>


            <executions>
                <execution>

                <id>integration-tests</id>
                <phase>integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                <configuration>
                <skip>false</skip>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>none</exclude>
                </excludes>

                <includes>
                   <include>**/integration/*Test.java</include>
                </includes>
                </configuration>
                </execution>
        </executions>

        </plugin>
```

what happens is as follows:

1. war file is created.
2. integration test class runs (open the browser, then the browser close).
3. tomcat server starts and deploys the application.
4. **ISSUE:** after deploy i get **java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space** although i increased the memory in catalina.bat and in cargo configuration, but i can see that the war is deployed in the cargo output folder, so i am wondering why i am getting this exception ?

**UPDATE**: LOGS

```
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer] Jan 16, 2012 1:36:51 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.SetAllPropertiesRule begin
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer] WARNING: [SetAllPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Connector} Setting property 'emptySessionPath' to 'true' did not find a matching property.
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer] Jan 16, 2012 1:36:51 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer] WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host} Setting property 'xmlValidation' to 'false' did not find a matching property.
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer] Jan 16, 2012 1:36:51 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer] WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host} Setting property 'xmlNamespaceAware' to 'false' did not find a matching property
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer] Jan 16, 2012 1:36:51 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer] INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer] Jan 16, 2012 1:36:51 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer] INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer] Jan 16, 2012 1:36:51 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer] INFO: Initialization processed in 600 ms
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer] Jan 16, 2012 1:36:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer] INFO: Starting service Catalina
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer] Jan 16, 2012 1:36:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer] INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.22
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer] Jan 16, 2012 1:36:51 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer] INFO: Deploying web application archive cargocpc.war
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer] Jan 16, 2012 1:36:52 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer] INFO: Deploying web application archive MyAPP.war
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer] java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer]        at java.lang.Throwable.getStackTraceElement(Native Method)
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer]        at java.lang.Throwable.getOurStackTrace(Throwable.java:591)
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer]        at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:462)
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer]        at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:451)
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer]        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:469)
```

Answer (score 4):

- I am using now the following profile and it works fine, i run the integration test with

  ```
   mvn install -Pit
  ```

**Profile**:

```
<profile>
          <id>it</id>
          <build>
           <plugins>

           <plugin>

            <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.4</version>
            <configuration>

                <wait>false</wait> 
                <container>
                 <containerId>tomcat7x</containerId>
                 <home>${env.CATALINA_HOME}</home>  
                 <timeout>300000</timeout>                  
                </container>

                <configuration>
                 <type>standalone</type>
                 <home>target/tomcat7x</home> 
                 <properties>
                  <cargo.jvmargs>-XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled</cargo.jvmargs>
                </properties> 
                </configuration>


            </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                    <id>start-container</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>start</goal>
                            <goal>deploy</goal>
                        </goals>

                        <configuration>
                            <deployer>
                                <deployables>
                                    <deployable>
                                    <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                                    <type>war</type>
                                    <pingURL>http://localhost:8080/${project.artifactId}</pingURL>
                                    <pingTimeout>60000</pingTimeout>
                                    <properties>
                                        <context>${project.artifactId}</context>
                                    </properties>
                                    </deployable>
                                </deployables>
                            </deployer>
                        </configuration>

                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                    <id>stop-container</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>stop</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
          </plugin>


        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <executions>
                    <execution>
                    <id>start</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>start-server</goal>
                        </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <background>true</background>
                        <logOutput>true</logOutput>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>

                <execution>
                <id>stop</id>
                <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>stop-server</goal>
                        </goals>
                </execution> 
            </executions>
    </plugin>


             <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>

                        <execution>
                            <id>default-test</id>                                
                            <configuration>
                                <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>

                        <execution>
                            <id>surefire-it</id>
                            <phase>integration-test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>test</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>**/integration/*Test.java</include>
                                </includes>
                                <skipTests>false</skipTests>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <argLine>-Xms256M -Xmx768M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M</argLine>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

              </plugins>
            </build>

            <activation>
              <property>
                <name>it</name>
              </property>
            </activation>

        </profile>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `MAVEN_OPTS=-XX:MaxPermSize=384m` (or some suitable number) in the environment variables of where you're running the maven build.

Comment: i already have `MAVEN_OPTS=-Xmx512m -Xms256m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m`

Comment: Where exactly in the build does it happen? Can you post an extract of the output?

Comment: Try checking using jconsole that the tomcat instance is actually receiving the PermGen override